# Select certain properties (fields) when using BOTH in Orient SQL

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

Using OrientDB 2.* with OrientSQL.

I have a simple graph with Class `Users` that has a number of properties (username, country, pets, etc). Each user also has outgoing `friends` edge. I want to select only the `username` and `country` from all users who are friends with a specific user.

My query so far:

```
SELECT EXPAND( BOTH('friends') ) FROM users WHERE @rid = #12:0
```

returns the full user objects for those who are friends of `#12:0`

I want only to return the `username` and `country` of those friends.

Am I missing something simple? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
select expand(both('friends').include('username', 'country')) 
from #12:0
```

---

Note that you should:

```
select from #12:0
```

instead of:

```
select from Users where @rid = #12:0
```

Comment: Where did you find the include keyword ? I cannot find this information in the documentation

Comment: I'm not sure it's there. I've seen it somewhere.

Comment: there's __exclude__ too.

Comment: thankyou +1 ! I guess your answer is better... I just posted a question with the orientdb tag. can you take a look at it I need help with orientjs/oriento ?

Comment: Never used it, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

A sub-query would work. I don't think there is any other way to do this.

Try this :

```
select 
   username, country 
from (select 
         expand( both('friends') ) 
      from 
         #12:0)
```